# How to enable / disable player movement in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

So, I'm making a game where one player changes control of two characters with the press of shift, so, when shift is pressed, the player 1 movement is disabled and the player 2 script is enabled, I approached this by making the movement speed and jump reach numbers as zero, but when shift is pressed, nothing happens, what can I do to counter this?

By the way, I set the Fire2 for "shift" to clarify, and also focus on the "CanPlay" variable, because it's where I think the problem is.

Code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movimento : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool CanPlay;

    void Update()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float speedY = PlayerRB.velocity.y;

        PlayerRB.velocity = new Vector2(h * speed, speedY);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && Isgrounded == true)
        {
            PlayerRB.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpforce));
        }

        if (h > 0 && IsLookLeft == true)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if (h < 0 && IsLookLeft == false)
        {
            Flip();
        }

        if (CanPlay = false)
        {
            speed = 0f;
            jumpforce = 0f;
        } 

        if (CanPlay = true)
        {
            speed = 10f;
            jumpforce = 150f;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("Fire2"))
        {
            CanPlay = !CanPlay;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your if's. It should be:

```
if (CanPlay == false)
    {
        speed = 0f;
        jumpforce = 0f;
    }

    if (CanPlay == true)
    {
        speed = 10f;
        jumpforce = 150f;
    }
```